# ASIHTTPRequest getting status 0, and headers null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am using `ASIHTTPRequest`, at times i use to get the response status as `0`, and when i printed the response status headers, i get `null`.

What does this mean, and what should i do to handle this programatically ?

```
-(void)requestWentWrong:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

 NSLog(@"header %@", [request responseHeaders]);
NSLog(@"stat code %i", [request responseStatusCode]);
}
```

Comment: For your info, ASIHTTPRequest is being deprecated. You may want to read: http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D; and  http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/04/asihttprequest-is-dead.-long-live-mknetworkkit.

Comment: Does this mean apple will reject my application ? and i have tried MKNetworkKit before, there's less information available about it and no help in forums

Comment: No, Apple will not reject your application due to use of ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: You can use ASIHttpRequest without problem, it was just for your information. I haven't tried the alternatives yet.

Answer (score 0):

The request could be failing for a number of reasons - try logging any error, eg:

```
NSLog("request %@ failed with error @%", request, request.error);
```